# c# enum reflection, get name when multiple names

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

Consider the following

```
public enum E
{
  A = 1,
  B = 1  
}

public string F(E input)
{
 return input.ToString();
}

F(E.B); //returns "A"
```

Now I know that you're not supposed to do `((E)1).ToString()`, as it could resolve to `A` or `B` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx).
But when it's an explicitly chosen value (e.g. `B`), why does `ToString()` behave wierdly (returning `A`)?

When debugging its possible to see that `input` is `B`, is it possible to get the selected field in code?

**EDIT**
This question relates to how the debugger knows which value is passed to `F()`, whilst in code it doesn't seem possible to detect this?

Comment: enum members is actualy numbers, named constants, so it works correctly

Comment: You would expect that F(E.B) would return "B" not "A"

Comment: I understand that enums are names for underlying values. What im trying to figure out is when an enum has 2+ names for the same underlying value the behaviour is different to expected

Comment: When you write `E.B` fraemwork translate it to the concreate number in your example it is 1. And when it will  try to parse/resolve it will look in the enum definitaion to try to find named member for this number and it will select first item. Enum is not a reference type.

Comment: @SimonLaing - Why are you doing this in the first place? This is highly unusual.

Comment: Enums with the multiple names for the same underlying value are acceptable, the behaviour is provides is to have an alias for the same value

Comment: In the reference that you gave, it read :"The following method call attempts to retrieve the name of a member of the Shade enumeration whose underlying value is 1. The method can return either "Gray" or "Grey", and your **bold**code should not make any assumptions about which string will be returned**bold**."

Comment: My reason for asking is an exercise to understand whats going on, as the debugger can read the correct name - but in code you cannot?

Comment: @Stephan, yes this statement is correct, this shows an example where `1` is cast to the enum type. Its obvious that this could resolve to either Grey or Gray. My question is when a specific enum name is chosen why is that information lost after a method call?

Comment: I would expect `E.A.ToString() == E.B.ToString()`, but the spec does not even guarantee that. I wouldn't expect `E.A.ToString() != E.B.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ist that the two possible enum values `A` and `B` both have an integer value of `1`, making it impossible to make the distinction between `A` and `B` since C# just passes a value of `1` as argument to the method.

Comment: Ok, i understand that c# will pass `1` in the method call, but how does the debugger know which enum name this came from, i.e. `B`

Comment: @SimonLaing The debugger doesn't know that.

Comment: When breaking in `F(E.B)` its possible to see the value of `input`, which will be shown as `B`

Comment: Let me try to reproduce the problem, i wrote the question from a rough copy of the issue i experienced earlier today

Comment: Apologies, I cannot seem to reproduce the problem at the moment. My debugger also shows `E.A`

Answer (score 2):

The enum is really just an integer value.  What happens is that, when you call `input.ToString()`, the enum does the following:

- Get the value of input, in this case, `1`
- Passes this to an internal formatting routine, which finds the matching name (if this isn't decorated with `[Flags]`)
- Returns the name

When it goes to find the matching name, it finds the *first* match with a value of 1, in this case, `E.A`, and prints "A".

Normally, this isn't a problem, as you would typically only have one enum value per name.

> When debugging its possible to see that input is B, is it possible to get the selected field in code?

The problem is that `input` is not "B" - the input is a value of 1 wrapped in an `E` variable, which means that input is `E.A` **and** `E.B`.

To demonstrate, run:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    public enum E
    {
        A = 1,
        B = 1
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        E value = E.B;


        Console.WriteLine(value == E.B);
        Console.WriteLine(value == E.A);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

This will print `True` twice, as `value` is both `E.A` and `E.B`.

If you break on `Console.ReadKey`, the debugger will show `value` as "A", as well.

Comment: I'm not sure it always finds the "first" match. And if it does, is it first wrt. the textual order of the source code, or first wrt. the numerical value? [The doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z) says: _If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return._

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Which is absolutely true - you shouldn't make any assumptions about it.  The current implementation does happen to put it in textual order, so with the MS stack, it finds the first value, though.  It's just not guaranteed by spec.

Comment: Yes you're exactly right, but in your example, if you break after `E value = E.B` the debugger shows that `value` is `B` not `A`/both/unknown

Comment: Apologies, I cannot seem to reproduce the problem at the moment.